# Something to dynamically Generate a UI to edit XML file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xml, user-interface

I have an XML file with a lot of nodes similar to the following format:

```
<Factsheet page="GenericOfflineFactsheet.aspx" pageTitle="MyTitle" >
  <TopStrapline text="BlahBlahBlah" />
  <Commentary page="Text.ascx" />
  <ChartPanel page="Bar.ascx" appearanceFile="Bar.xml" />
  <Strapline text="blah blah blah" />
  <Funds>
    <fund id="215" countryid="N0" />
    <fund id="561" countryid="N0" />
  </Funds>
  <LegalText effectiveDate="08 June 2010">
    <Line id="30321" />
    <Line id="10301" />
  </LegalText>
</Factsheet>
```

Is there any free plugins (or any other means) out there that I could use in an ASP.NET MVC application to generate a basic UI for editing this kind of file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about LinqToXML?  Then you can use this as your model in your controllers and views just like LinqToSQL.

[LinqToXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: I understand I can use LinqToXML to get the data but can I somehow dynamically generate the UI with it? Thanks

Comment: Once you setup LinqToXML classes, MVC should use its scaffolding to build your create/edit/index views when you create them given that you choose a strongly typed view.